# Убрать зуминг страницы после выбора в нативном дропдауне

Tags: css, ios, mobile, responsive

На мобильной версии сайта, после выбора значения в нативном дропдауне страница увеличивается (зумиться).Как это можно  исправить помимо добавления метатега в head?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Яблочные устройства могут слегка зумить нативные контролы если размер шрифта в них меньше 16px.

Соответственно если увеличить размер шрифта в контролах то ненужный зум по выбору контрола исчезнет, но юзер по прежнему сможет изменять размер страницы.

В духе:

```
select{
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Разумеется это можно обернуть в медиа запрос или вешать правило по классам а не по тегу.